# Adding a custom attribute after the short description in magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I'm quite new to magento and i'm struggling trying to add a custom attribute after the short description in products page

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
<div class="short-description">
<div class="std"<?php if($richSnippets['status'] == 1): ?> itemprop="description"<?php endif; ?>><h2><?php echo $this->__('Details:') ?></h2><?php echo $_helper>productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>

<?php $_item = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$_resource = $this->getProduct()->getResource();
$CustomAttribute = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($_item, 'ratebeer', Mage::app()->getStore());
echo $CustomAttribute; ?>
```

Anyway the attribute does not appear after the short description...the same code works in another section of the same page so i don't really know what's going on

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just

```
echo $_product->getRatebeer();
```

But you may have to add the attribute to your flat tables first.  You can do this by setting `Include in product listing` to Yes.

This is bad practice, but you could try this just to see if the attribute is set up correctly

```
echo $_product->load($_product->getId())->getRatebeer();
```